# How to extract specific lines from a text file and then from these extracted line, extract the values between parantheses and put them in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, data-analysis, data-extraction

```
infile = open('results1', 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()
import re
for line in lines:
if re.match("track: 1,", line):
    print(line)
```

question solved by using python regex below

Comment: You should also include your current Python script, even if half-baked, but at the very least please show the output file you want from the sample input above.

Comment: Welcome to SO!!.  Consider using python regex for such problems. You will get clean answers to such problems :).

Comment: I added the code i am currently using and i already got the line i wanted but still can't figure out how to get the values between parantheses and how to store them in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Regular Expressions library (re) which gives you all you need to extract the data from text files. I ran a simple code to solve your current problem:

```
import re
# Customize path as the file's address on your system
text_file = open('path/sample.txt','r')
# Read the file line by line using .readlines(), so that each line will be a continuous long string in the "file_lines" list
file_lines = text_file.readlines()
```

Depending on how your target is located in each line, detailed process from here on could be a little different but the overall approach is the same in every scenario.
I have assumed your only condition is that the line starts with "Id of the track" and we are looking to extract all the values between parentheses all in one place.

```
# A list to append extracted data
list_extracted_data = []
for line in list_lines:
# Flag is True if the line starts (special character for start: \A) with 'Id of the track'
    flag = re.search('\AId of the track',line)
    if flag:
        searched_phrase = re.search(r'\B\(.*',line)
        start_index, end_index = searched_phrase.start(), searched_phrase.end()
# Select the indices from each line as it contains our extracted data
        list_extracted_data.append(line[start_index:end_index])
        
print(list_extracted_data)
```

> ['(0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)', '(0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)', '(0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)', '(0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)', '(0.8755597308669424, -0.23473345870373538)', '(0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)', '(0.8755597308669424, -0.23473345870373538)', '(6.4057079727806485, -0.6819141582566414)', '(1.1815888836384334,
> -0.35535274681454954)']

you can do all sorts of things after you've selected the data from each line, including convert it to numerical type or separating the two numbers inside the parentheses.
I assume your intention was to add each of the numbers inside into a different column in a dataFrame:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','X','Y'])
for K, pair in enumerate(list_extracted_data):
    # split by comma, select the left part, exclude the '(' at the start
    this_X = float(pair.split(',')[0][1:])
    # split by comma, select the right part, exclude the ')' at the end
    this_Y = float(pair.split(',')[1][:-1])
    final_df = final_df.append({'id':K,'X':this_X,'Y':this_Y},ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) this works perfectly!!!! i just have another question, if i wanted to save this values between the parantheses in separated files bases on the number of the track, in other words, give the global file and extract the values of each number of track and put it in new separeted files

Comment: @cosmicdust Then you should also search for the track number inside the "if" . 
you can create a new search phrase as searched_phrase = re.search(r'\Btrack:.*',line).
and then instead of appending it into a list, you should append it to a dictionary where keys are your track numbers and values are what's inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Given that all your target lines follow the exact same pattern, a much simpler way to extract the value between parentheses would be:

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
infile = open('results1', 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()
import re

for line in lines:
    if re.match("Id of the track: 1,", line):
        values_slice = line.split(": ")[-1]
        values = make_tuple(values_slice)    # stored as tuple => (0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)
```

Now you can use/manipulate/store the values whichever way you want.